# Google Analytics drop not showing in HubSpot Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, hubspot, web-traffic

I've been trying to figure out why our Google Analytics data is not matching our HubSpot Analytic data. According to GA, our traffic drops off significantly on October 31 (much more than usual). Since then, according to GA, our website traffic has not recovered. However, according to HubSpot, our traffic data is normal and does not show any drop.

I've contacted HubSpot support and our GA tracking code is properly installed on all pages. Can anyone tell me why our GA traffic data is not showing the same information we're seeing in HubSpot data?

See attached images.

[Google Analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS7A1.png)

[HubSpot Analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPirZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your Google analytics. Maybe a tag manager bug, or a cookie banner was added?

Hubspot analytics (when hosted on hubspot) seems to be using cookieless tracking using a .gif file, that is not affected by cookie consents.